# Complexity of T(n)=2T(n-1)

Tags: complexity-theory, recursion, big-o-notation

I built a recursion tree like this:

```
  0  
 / \  
 0  0  
/\ /\  
... ...
```

So the tree has height n, and width $2^n$.
But if the sum of all levels is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}0$, then is the function simply $O(1)$?

Comment: You are missing the base cases from your recurrence relations. I suspect it is $T(1)=1$. You might want to redraw the tree with this in mind.

Comment: The title of the post is wrong. And there is no connection between the width $2^n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n$.

Comment: "is the function $O(1)$ ?": which function ??

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of $T(n)=2T(n-1) + 0$.  The problem, like @Steven says, is that you need a base case.  To see it even more clearly than your illustration, simply try rewriting the function.  For example, write $T(n)=2T(n-1) + 0 = 2(\underbrace{ 2T(n-2)+0 }_{T(n-1)}) + 0 = 2( 2(\underbrace{2T(n-3)+0}_{T(n-2)}) + 0 ) + 0 = \dots$.  Eventually, you will still need the function $T(n-k)$ for some $k$.  This function, $T(n-k)$, doesn't need to be constant.  i.e. it could be a function of $n$.  It could also be $0$, which is even faster than a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

A sum of $m$ constants takes time $O(m)$.